# Backbone model is kept from changing

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-events

My app uses Backbone. It has a model that users can change. This model must be validated before being changed. If it has changed, a function is called. When users click on save, the model is saved if and only if it has changed.

My problem is that when the change event is fired the model has no longer changed, therefore it will not be saved.

Here is the code: http://jsfiddle.net/keepyourweb/jQL8V/

```js
var model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
    },
    default: {
        'first_name': 'none',
        'last_name': 'none'   
    },
    validate: function(attr) {
        if (_.isEmpty(attr['first_name'])) return 'Error name required';   
    }
});

var test = new model,
    showError = function(model, error) {
        alert(error);   
    },
    changed = function() {
        alert('changed!');   
    };

test.bind('change', changed);
test.set({'first_name': 'test_name', 'last_name': 'test_surname'}, {error: showError});

$('#save').bind('click', function() {
   if (test.hasChanged()) alert('Saved!!');  
});
```

Comment: the documentation states: "Note that this method, and the following change-related ones, are only useful during the course of a `change` event." so guess you will need to look for another test to see if the model has changed. (more info: http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-hasChanged)

Comment: ehm yes...my issue is just that: which test to do

Comment: well i don't feel ready to post this in an answer yet, since i have not tried it myself or don't have any code examples, but you might try to write the check yourself, bind to the change event, and set a custom attribute to true, then test if that attribute is true, and post the values and after the post set the custom attribute back to false.

Comment: I put the link for the example code above.
However, I thought myself in this solution but I don't really like...but I feel that it's the unique.